# LDAP, AD и сертификаты. А также ошибка #-1

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

**Суть задачи:** нужно с AD, используя ldap, тянуть данные о пользователе.

**Проблема:** Не работает. 99% решений в сети сводятся к TLS_REQCERT=never, но в моем случае, использованные сертификата обязательно. Сертификат есть, но оно не работает.

**Детали:**
В общем в компании решили, все права пользователей хранить в AD. Он и до того использовался, но теперь это коснулось нашего проекта. От админов получила урезанный доступ к серверу а также сертификат (*.pem).

Дальше я попробовала запустить код, аналогов которого в сети полно. И как не старайся, оно нормально не работает. Самое смешное то, что все это иногда таки работает. Трижды (или больше) может вернуть ошибку #-1 (при том, что в документации номера ошибок начинаются с 0!), потом несколько раз подтянуть данные о пользователи, и так по кругу.

Как уже писала, 99% решений это TLS_REQCERT=never, но сертификат нужен. Питалась решить проблему самостоятельно, с админами, но глухо.

Вот пример кода (каких полно в сети):

```
// PHP version: 7.0.4
putenv("LDAPCACERT=" . '/storage/www/.secret/ldap/ca.pem');
//putenv("LDAPCACERT=" . '/storage/www/.secret/ldap/ca-ssl.pem');
 
$Email          = 'user.mail@mail.com';
$LDAPConnection = ldap_connect("ldaps://ldap.software.com", 636);
if (ldap_bind($LDAPConnection, 'ad-google-user@g5mail.com', 'pass_123456789'))
{
  $RK = ldap_search($LDAPConnection, 'OU=SOFT Domain,dc=software,dc=com', "(mail={$Email})");
  $Results = ldap_get_entries($LDAPConnection, $RK);
  print_r($Results);
  echo "\n";
  ldap_close($LDAPConnection);
}
else
  echo "Error #" . ldap_errno($LDAPConnection) . ": " . ldap_error($LDAPConnection);
 
die();
```

Пример ответа с ошибкой:
[image: Пример ответа с ошибкой]

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая проблема, правда в приложении .Net Core, но это не важно.

> Самое смешное то, что все это иногда таки работает.

У меня эти чудеса пропали и все заработало, когда я вместо имени сервера стал указывать его IP в строке подключения. Может показаться банальным, но попробуйте.

Кстати, имя пользоваьеля указывал как "zoneName\userName" или "userName@zoneName.zonePostfix" (user123@software.com).

Comment: Идея хорошая. Попробовала. Но ответ все еще приходит через раз

Answer (score 0):

Нашла причину проблемы и решение.

**Причина:** если запускать скрипт через **nginx** + **php-fpm**, **ldap не будет воспринимать большинство опций** установленных через **putenv** или **ldap_set_option**. Также, пока не **перезапустить php-fpm**, изменения с основного конфига ldap (/etc/openldap/ldap.conf или /etc/ldap/ldap.conf) также не будут применяться.

**Решение:** ldap все же читает опцию **LDAPCONF** в которой можно установить путь к файлу с конфигом для проекта, и уже там указать путь к сертификату. Но после каждого изменения в конфиге, все еще нужно **перезапускать php-fpm**

```
#############################################
// *.php файл 
putenv('LDAPCONF=/path/to/project/ldap.conf');
$Connect = ldap_connect($LDAPHostName, $Port);
$IsConnected = ldap_bind($Connect, $SysUserLogin, LDAP_PASS);
// и все стабильно работает

#############################################
// project/ldap.conf
VERSION 3
TLS_REQCERT demand
TLS_CACERT /storage/www/.secret/ldap/ca.pem
```

Если же запускать скрипт через консоль, никаких перезагрузок не надо. И ldap_set_option работает. Понятия не имею, почему творить такая ересь, но надеюсь это первый и последний раз, когда мне приходилось разбираться с ldap.